# In Tcl fetch index value using regexp

Tags: tcl

I am trying to fetch index value from particular line which is found inside the file.
the line is

```
   + ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE ( 69768 89000 ) ( 95146 * )
```

here only **ROUTED* is constant, i want fetch values between parenthesis  **( 69768 89000 ) ( 95146 * )* as **Vxx 69768,  Vxy 89000,  Vyx 95146,  Vyy *,*

Here my code

```
set input_file [open "M12_expt.def" r]
set output_file [open "M12_expt_newloc.def" w]

while {[gets $input_file line] >=0} {
    if {[string match {*ROUTED*} $line]} {

set start [expr {[string first "(" $line] + 1}]
    set end [string last ")" $line]
    set values [string range $line $start $end]
    set vlist [regexp -inline {\d+|\*} $values]
puts $vlist
    set vxx [lindex $vlist 0]
    set vxy [lindex $vlist 1]
    set vyx [lindex $vlist 2]
    set vyy [lindex $vlist 3]
    puts "vxx $vxx"
    puts "vxy $vxy"
    puts "vyx $vyx"
    puts "vyy $vyy" 
  }
}
```

where my expected result is

```
vxx 69768
vxy 89000
vyx 95146
vyy *
```

but for me getting this result

```
vxx 69768
vxy 
vyx 
vyy
```

can anyone correct my mistake in the code? let me know what wrong I did? :(

Comment: Forgot the -all option in the regexp command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the input data:

```
   + ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE ( 69768 89000 ) ( 95146 * )
```

and you want to determine:

1. Does the line match (is `ROUTED` present)?
2. What are the quadruple of values from the parenthesis-enclosed parts? (`69768`, `89000`, `95146` and `*` in this case)

The `regexp` command is the right tool for this.

```
set input "   + ROUTED M12 10000 + SHAPE STRIPE ( 69768 89000 ) ( 95146 * )"
set RE {ROUTED[^(]+\(\s*([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)\s*\(\s*([^\s()]+)\s+([^\s()]+)\s*\)}

if {[regexp $RE $input -> Vxx Vxy Vyx Vyy]} {
    puts "Vxx = $Vxx"
    puts "Vxy = $Vxy"
    puts "Vyx = $Vyx"
    puts "Vyy = $Vyy"
}
```

It looks like a fearsome regular expression to start with, but the key subcomponent is this: `([^\s()]+)`. That matches and captures a non-empty sequence of characters other than whitespace or parentheses. The overall RE uses four of those plus a bit of literal matching and careful pattern choice to skip over the bits you don't want. (You probably ought to look for `STRIPE` too, in case your data isn't 100% rectilinear stripes.)

Comment: I quite like to put big REs in their own variable. Lets me name them.